# How do ı make continiously mathematical operations in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to advance my calculator and I want it to make continiously mathematical operations with the last number of calculation. for example

11+2=13

and than take the 13 and us it in the next calculation

13 x 3= 39

and than after using the 39 like

39%3=13

instead of this my code works like

11+2=13

13*3=39

and goes back to first conclusion and be like

11 *? =...

ıt alvays goes back to first conclusion after second calculation. how can ı make it continiously until ı want it to be stopped?

```
def addition(str):
    "addition"
    print(str)
    return
def subtraction(str):
        "subtraction"
        print(str)
        return
def multiplation(str):
    "multiplation"
    return
def division(str):
    "division"
    print(str)
    return
def exponantial_notation(str):
    "exponantial notation"
    print(str)
    return
def yes(str):
    "yes"
    print(str)
    return
def no(str):
    "no"
    print(str)
    return
def dif(str):
    "dif"
    print(str)
    return
def div(str):
    "def"
    print(str)
    return
def sum(str):
    "sum"
    print(str)
    return
def mul(str):
    "mul"
    print(str)
    return
def exp(str):
    "exp"
    print(str)
    return

while True:
        mathematical_operation=input("Choose your mathematical operation(addition/subtraction/multiplication/division/exponantial notation/root): ")
        print(mathematical_operation)

        if mathematical_operation== 'addition':
            first=input("first: ")
            print("first")
            second=input("second: ")
            print("second")
            sum=float(first) + float(second)
            print("sum :" + str(sum))
            while True:
                continiune = input("would you like to go on?")
                if continiune == 'yes':
                    mathematical_operation = input(
                        "Choose your mathematical operation(addition/subtraction/multiplication/division/exponantial notation/root): ")
                print(mathematical_operation)
                if mathematical_operation == 'addition':
                    print("first: " + str(sum))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    sum = float(str(sum)) + float(second)
                    print("sum :" + str(sum))
                if mathematical_operation == 'subtraction':
                    print("first: " + str(sum))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    dif = float(str(sum)) - float(second)
                    print("dif :" + str(dif))
                if mathematical_operation == 'multiplication':
                    print("first: " + str(sum))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    mul = float(str(sum)) * float(second)
                    print("mul: " + str(mul))
                if mathematical_operation == 'division':
                    print("first: " + str(sum))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    div = float(str(sum)) / float(second)
                    print("div: " + str(div))
                if mathematical_operation == 'exponantial notation':
                    print("first: " + str(sum))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    exp = float(str(sum)) ** float(second)
                    print("exp: " + str(exp))
                if continiune == 'no':
                    break
            question = input("would you like to make another calculation?(yes/no) ")
            if question == 'no':
               break

        if mathematical_operation == 'subtraction':
            first = input("first: ")
            print("first")
            second = input("second: ")
            print("second")
            dif = float(first) - float(second)
            print("dif :" + str(dif))
            while True:
                continiune = input("would you like to go on?")
                if continiune == 'yes':
                    mathematical_operation = input(
                        "Choose your mathematical operation(addition/subtraction/multiplication/division/exponantial notation/root): ")
                print(mathematical_operation)
                if mathematical_operation == 'addition':
                    print("first: " + str(dif))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    sum = float(str(dif)) + float(second)
                    print("sum :" + str(sum))
                if mathematical_operation == 'subtraction':
                    print("first: " + str(dif))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    dif = float(str(dif)) - float(second)
                    print("dif :" + str(dif))
                if mathematical_operation == 'multiplication':
                    print("first: " + str(dif))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    mul = float(str(dif)) * float(second)
                    print("mul: " + str(mul))
                if mathematical_operation == 'division':
                    print("first: " + str(dif))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    div = float(str(dif)) / float(second)
                    print("div: " + str(div))
                if mathematical_operation == 'exponantial notation':
                    print("first: " + str(dif))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    exp = float(str(dif)) ** float(second)
                    print("exp: " + str(exp))
                if continiune == 'no':
                    break
            question = input("would you like to make another calculation?(yes/no) ")
            if question == 'no':
                break

        if mathematical_operation=='multiplication':
            first=input("first: ")
            print("first")
            second=input("second: ")
            print("second")
            mul=float(first) *float(second)
            print("Sum :" + str(mul))
            while True:
                continiune = input("would you like to go on?")
                if continiune == 'yes':
                    mathematical_operation = input(
                        "Choose your mathematical operation(addition/subtraction/multiplication/division/exponantial notation/root): ")
                print(mathematical_operation)
                if mathematical_operation == 'addition':
                    print("first: " + str(mul))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    sum = float(str(mul)) + float(second)
                    print("sum :" + str(sum))
                if mathematical_operation == 'subtraction':
                    print("first: " + str(mul))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    dif = float(str(mul)) - float(second)
                    print("dif :" + str(dif))
                if mathematical_operation == 'multiplication':
                    print("first: " + str(mul))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    mul = float(str(mul)) * float(second)
                    print("mul: " + str(mul))
                if mathematical_operation == 'division':
                    print("first: " + str(mul))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    div = float(str(mul)) / float(second)
                    print("div: " + str(div))
                if mathematical_operation == 'exponantial notation':
                    print("first: " + str(mul))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    exp = float(str(mul)) ** float(second)
                    print("exp: " + str(exp))
                if continiune == 'no':
                    break
            question = input("would you like to make another calculation?(yes/no) ")
            if question == 'no':
                break

        if mathematical_operation=='division':
            first=input("first: ")
            print("first")
            second=input("second: ")
            print("second")
            div=float(first) /float(second)
            print("div :" + str(div))
            while True:
                continiune = input("would you like to go on?")
                if continiune == 'yes':
                    mathematical_operation = input(
                        "Choose your mathematical operation(addition/subtraction/multiplication/division/exponantial notation/root): ")
                print(mathematical_operation)
                if mathematical_operation == 'addition':
                    print("first: " + str(div))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    sum = float(str(div)) + float(second)
                    print("sum :" + str(sum))
                if mathematical_operation == 'subtraction':
                    print("first: " + str(div))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    dif = float(str(div)) - float(second)
                    print("dif :" + str(dif))
                if mathematical_operation == 'multiplication':
                    print("first: " + str(div))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    mul = float(str(div)) * float(second)
                    print("mul: " + str(mul))
                if mathematical_operation == 'division':
                    print("first: " + str(div))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    div = float(str(div)) / float(second)
                    print("div: " + str(div))
                if mathematical_operation == 'exponantial notation':
                    print("first: " + str(div))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    exp = float(str(div)) ** float(second)
                    print("exp: " + str(exp))
                if continiune == 'no':
                    break
            question = input("would you like to make another calculation?(yes/no) ")
            if question == 'no':
                break

        if mathematical_operation=='exponantial notation':
            first=input("first: ")
            print("first: ")
            second=input("second")
            print("second")
            exp=float(first) **float(second)
            print("sum :" + str(exp))
            question = input("would you like to make another calculation?(yes/no) ")
            while True:
                continiune = input("would you like to go on?")
                if continiune == 'yes':
                    mathematical_operation = input(
                        "Choose your mathematical operation(addition/subtraction/multiplication/division/exponantial notation/root): ")
                print(mathematical_operation)
                if mathematical_operation == 'addition':
                    print("first: " + str(exp))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    sum = float(str(exp)) + float(second)
                    print("sum :" + str(sum))
                if mathematical_operation == 'subtraction':
                    print("first: " + str(exp))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    dif = float(str(exp)) - float(second)
                    print("dif :" + str(dif))
                if mathematical_operation == 'multiplication':
                    print("first: " + str(exp))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    mul = float(str(exp)) * float(second)
                    print("mul: " + str(mul))
                if mathematical_operation == 'division':
                    print("first: " + str(exp))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    div = float(str(exp)) / float(second)
                    print("div: " + str(div))
                if mathematical_operation == 'exponantial notation':
                    print("first: " + str(exp))
                    second = input("second: ")
                    print(second)
                    exp = float(str(exp)) ** float(second)
                    print("exp: " + str(exp))
                if continiune == 'no':
                    break
            if question == 'no':
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
```

Comment: can you show some more of your code so that we can help break down the problem.  There are a bunch of ways to do this, so I want to make sure you're getting the right solution

Comment: @finman69 this was my whole code ,there is this barriere that is why ı cant go forvard :(

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where to begin explaining where your approach is misguided and broken, though I would be happy to try if you have further questions.  There are many ways to write a simple calculator program.  Here's one I just wrote to give you some better ideas of how to approach this (it's probably missing a few things and buggy, but it should show you how little code you actually need to write for this).  This also uses regular expressions which may be a concept you haven't studied yet, but it can also be done without a regular expession (and is even recommended if you want to support things like parentheses):

calc.py

```
import operator
import re


infix_ops = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
    '**': operator.pow
}


num_re = r'-?(?:\d+)?.?\d+'


infix_expr_re = re.compile(
    r'({num})\s*({ops})\s*({num})'.format(
        num=num_re, ops='|'.join(re.escape(op) for op in infix_ops))
)


def calculator():
    result = None

    while True:
        try:
            if result is None:
                expr = input()
            else:
                expr = str(result) + input(str(result) + ' ')
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
            print()
            print('goodbye')
            break

        if not (m := infix_expr_re.match(expr)):
            print(f'invalid expression: {expr}')
            continue

        lhs, op, rhs = m.groups()
        result = infix_ops[op](float(lhs), float(rhs))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    calculator()
```

Example calculation session:

```
$ python3 calc.py                                                                                                                                                       
1 + 1                                                                                                                                                                                         
2.0 * 3                                                                                                                                                                                       
6.0 ** 2                                                                                                                                                                                      
36.0 / 4                                                                                                                                                                                      
9.0 - 9                                                                                                                                                                                       
0.0 ^C                                                                                                                                                                                        
goodbye
```